# Is it possible to change the download file size limit in Alfresco Share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have one question about the donwload file size limit in Alfresco Share. 
When I download a large file, I got a message popup "The content is too large to download. The maximum download size is 2GB, the selected files are 2.9GB."
Is it possible to change this file size limit to 3GB or 4GB?
I think the message is catpured in the archive-and-download.js by below code

```
 archiveProgressSuccess: function ArchiveAndDownload_archiveProgressSuccess(response)
{

else if (response.json.status == "MAX_CONTENT_SIZE_EXCEEDED")
{
// The file size is too large to be zipped up:
Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayPrompt(
{
text: this.msg("message.maxContentSizeExceeded", Alfresco.util.formatFileSize(response.json.done), Alfresco.util.formatFileSize(response.json.total, 2))
});
this.panel.hide();
}
},
```

And this function is get called by

```
getArchivingProgress: function ArchiveAndDownload_getArchivingProgress(prevFailures)
{
if (this._currentArchiveNodeURL != null && this._currentArchiveNodeURL != "")
{
Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonGet({
url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "api/internal/downloads/" + this._currentArchiveNodeURL + "/status",
responseContentType : "application/json",
successCallback:
{
fn: this.archiveProgressSuccess,
scope: this
},
failureCallback:
{
fn: this.archiveProgressFailure,
scope: this
},
failureCount: prevFailures
});
}
},
```

Comment: What version of Alfresco Share are you using?

Comment: The version I am using is Community - 5.2.0 (r128301-b8)

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the solution by adding 
download.maxContentSize=-1
into alfresco-global.properties

Answer (score 1):

It is not as straight forward as it should, you can have a look here: http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/dev-extensions-share-module-dynamic-configuration.html

This is about upload but what is interesting is the `<in-memory-limit>262144000</in-memory-limit>` attribute

You might want to download big file using ftp or webdav from your share page

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/webdav/Sites/swsdp/documentLibrary/content.doc

or with wget

wget -r -nH -np -nv --cut-dirs=1 --user= --password= http://localhost:8080/alfresco/webdav/Sites/swsdp/documentLibrary/content.doc

Comment: Yes, that is for upload.  Is there any similar  attribute for download?

Comment: Not that I know, that's why I proposed the webdav solution. But I'm pretty sure something exist for the download it just is not exposed. I can't look at this right now as I've other thing I have to do but you might want to open the war of alfresco and check what exist in the different spring files. You'll probably find something like what exists for upload.